# How to pass a LINQ result to a method?

Tags: c#, linq, data-structures, anonymous-types

From [Efficient data structure to hold employee's activities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33699596/efficient-data-structure-to-hold-employees-activities) , i have a List of type ActividadEmpleado which is declared as:

```
public string Empleado { get; set; }
public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
public string Actividad { get; set; }
```

The LINQ query variable reorders the result in the way i need, which is to store by date and then by ActividadEmpleado and a string. However, var types cannot be passed to methods, so searching this site i am finding out that i either need to create a class to store the results or to modify the LINQ variable to return a List, but i am having issues with the proper declaration.

The LINQ variable is:

```
var queryActividades = listaActividad
                .GroupBy(a => a.Fecha, (fecha, fechaActividades) => new
                {
                    Fecha = fecha,
                    FechaActividades = fechaActividades
                        .GroupBy(a => a.Empleado, (nombreEmpleado, actividadesEmpleado) => new
                        {
                            Actividades = actividadesEmpleado,
                            NombreEmpleado = nombreEmpleado
                        })
                        .OrderBy(a => a.NombreEmpleado)
                })
                .OrderBy(a => a.Fecha);
```

Visual Studio says that queryActividades is:

```
IOrderedEnumerable<'a>
Anonymous Types:
'a new datetime fecha, iorderedenumerable<'b>
'b new IEnumerable<ActividadEmpleado> Actividades, string NombreEmpleado
```

I need to pass queryActividades to another method. I tried passing it as an Object but then i lose the extension methods such as Where<> (can i cast it somehow?)

I also read that declaring the results as a tuple should work, but i think declaring a new class is cleaner.

I am just starting with LINQ, i have avoided it to use regular data structures but in this case it's really helpful and would like to know how to either handle anonymous types in them or convert the result to a regular List

Final solution:

```
class GrupoActividad
{
    public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Actividad> Actividades { get; set; }
}

class Actividad
{
    public IEnumerable<ActividadEmpleado> Actividades { get; set; }
    public string NombreEmpleado { get; set; }
}

var queryActividades = listaActividad
                .GroupBy(a => a.Fecha, (fecha, fechaActividades) => new GrupoActividad
                {
                    Fecha = fecha,
                    Actividades = fechaActividades
                        .GroupBy(a => a.Empleado, (nombreEmpleado, actividadesEmpleado) => new Actividad
                        {
                            Actividades = actividadesEmpleado,
                            NombreEmpleado = nombreEmpleado
                        })
                        .OrderBy(a => a.NombreEmpleado)
                })
                .OrderBy(a => a.Fecha);
```

Receiving method:

```
var actividades = from a in queryActividades
                       where a.Fecha == fechaCiclo
                       select new { a.Fecha, a.Actividades };
            foreach (var item in actividades)
            {
                //cycle that holds each day's activities
                foreach (var empleado in item.Actividades)
                {
                    //cycle that holds each employee with activities in that day
                    foreach (var actividad in empleado.Actividades)
                    {
                        //final cycle that actually reads the activity
                        ActividadEmpleado actividadEmpleado = (ActividadEmpleado)actividad;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: `OrderBy(a => a.Fecha).ToList();`  ?

Comment: You can't pass anonymous types like typed objects, that won't work. Why don't you want use a tuple?

Comment: `var` is not a "type" - it just lets the compiler infer what the _actual_ type is.

Comment: Adding on to @YuvalItzchakov, what if you group them into a custom type in the query, so you have an `IEnumerable<YourType>`??

Comment: @DStanley I don't think he's referring to `var` as being the type. He's taking about the anonymous type he's creating for the `GroupBy`.

Comment: IEnumerable<dyanmic> might just work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass anonymous types as parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624811/how-to-pass-anonymous-types-as-parameters)

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov "However, var types cannot be passed to methods"

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov i am not against tuples, i just think that for novices like myself it would be just easier to understand to map the columns to a new class. Perhaps a example would clarify? idiot211 from what i have read IEnumerable<dynamic> has a performance cost. Ben Knoble i think that would be best, however i don't know enough LINQ to do so.

Comment: @fjleon `dynamic` does have a _slight_ performance cost but that should not be the driving reason not to use it.  The problem is that all binding (properties, methods, etc) is deferred until run-time.  So if you have a typo in your code or change a property name, you won't know that it fails until run-time.

Comment: @DStanley is right, the performance cost isn't massive, but the run time errors can kill your soul slowly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right now you are creating a collection that's based on an anonymous type (actually two anonymous types), which cannot practically be passed to another method (other than by using reflection or `dynamic`).  The cleanest way is to create a concrete type that represents the collection - something like

```
public class ActivityGroup
{
    public DateTime Fecha {get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<Activity> Activities {get; set;}
}

public class Activity
{
    public IEnumerable<Activity> Actividades {get; set;}
    public string NombreEmpleado {get; set;}
}
```

then change your query to:

```
var queryActividades = listaActividad
                .GroupBy(a => a.Fecha, (fecha, fechaActividades) => new ActivityGroup
                {
                    Fecha = fecha,
                    FechaActividades = fechaActividades
                        .GroupBy(a => a.Empleado, (nombreEmpleado, actividadesEmpleado) => new Activity
                        {
                            Actividades = actividadesEmpleado,
                            NombreEmpleado = nombreEmpleado
                        })
                        .OrderBy(a => a.NombreEmpleado)
                })
                .OrderBy(a => a.Fecha);
```

and pass it as an `IEnumerable<ActivityGroup>`

Comment: Had to change string Fecha to DateTime fecha in ActivityGroup, also rename FechaActividades to Activities (line 5 of the LINQ definition), but I am still getting errors at compile time: Cannot convert actividadesEmpleado to Actividades (line 8) and also cannot convert nombreEmpleado to NombreEmpleado (line 9). Should i remove the IEnumerable type in the classes?

Comment: @fjleon try my edit - i got the types of the inner type backwards.  And you do need the `IEnumerable<>` since the properties represent a collection.

Comment: Still errors: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ActividadesApoyo.ActividadEmpleado>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ActividadesApoyo.Actividad>'. Also, line 8 should say FechaActividades, not Actividades. Please see my edited question, the method that receives queryActividad should be able to apply a where clause as shown

Comment: I had to rename the attributes in the receiving method after my last edit in the comment before this one. Now it does work. I will update the question with the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the approach presented by D Stanley. But it would be kind a boring to have to create such classes for any similar query that you write in the future. Instead, you can introduce as generic class for that, like this

```
public class Grouping<TKey, TElement>
{
    public TKey Key { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<TElement> Elements { get; set; }
}
```

and use it instead of the anonymous types like this

```
var queryActividades = listaActividad
    .GroupBy(a => a.Fecha, (fecha, fechaActividades) => new Grouping<DateTime, Grouping<string, ActividadEmpleado>>
    {
        Key = fecha,
        Elements = fechaActividades
            .GroupBy(a => a.Empleado, (nombreEmpleado, actividadesEmpleado) => new Grouping<string, ActividadEmpleado>
            {
                Key = nombreEmpleado,
                Elements = actividadesEmpleado
            })
            .OrderBy(a => a.Key)
    })
    .OrderBy(a => a.Key);
```

which can be be passed as `IEnumerable<Grouping<DateTime, Grouping<string, ActividadEmpleado>>>`.

As you can see, there is a trade off between reusability and readability. Basically this is a `Tuple` with a little more meaningful names. Note that although we cannot improve the verbosity in the result, we can use a similar technique to `Tuple.Create` to remove the verbosity inside the query, by  adding a class like this

```
public static class Grouping
{
    public static Grouping<TKey, TElement> Create<TKey, TElement>(TKey key, IEnumerable<TElement> elements)
    {
        return new Grouping<TKey, TElement> { Key = key, Elements = elements };
    }
}
```

and use it like this

```
var queryActividades = listaActividad
    .GroupBy(a => a.Fecha, (fecha, fechaActividades) => Grouping.Create(
        fecha, fechaActividades
            .GroupBy(a => a.Empleado, (nombreEmpleado, actividadesEmpleado) => Grouping.Create(
                nombreEmpleado, actividadesEmpleado))
            .OrderBy(a => a.Key)))
    .OrderBy(a => a.Key);
```

Comment: very interesting, i will study this and save it somewhere :D, for now DStanley's solution (after a small change) works fine. Maybe i will change it, i like shorter code :)

Comment: @fjleon That's ok, I knew DStanley solution is fine at the time I wrote the above, but since you said you are starting with LINQ, decided to take some effort to provide you an option. Glad that you found it interesting, so the effort is worth enough :-) Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass anonymous types between methods; if you need to pass the data to another method, you need to create an explicit named type that contains the `Actividades` and `NombreEmpleado` properties, and another one with `Fecha` and `FechaActividades`.