# How to pass a grouped list as a parameter to a method in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I would like to pass as a parameter to a method a grouped list by type and id, how to properly pass this as a parameter and receive it in the method? I am using Visual Studio 2022 and groupedDocuments are type of List<IGrouping<'a, Document>>

```
public class Document
{  
    public int Id;
    public string DocumentType;
    public string Description;
}

public class Something()
{
     public void DoSomethingA(){
          List<Document> Documents = new List<Document>();
          Documents.Add(new Document { Id = 1, DocumentType = "TypeA", Description = 
          "DescriptionA" });
    Documents.Add(new Document { Id = 2, DocumentType = "TypeB", Description = 
          "DescriptionB" });
    Documents.Add(new Document { Id = 3, DocumentType = "TypeC", Description = 
          "DescriptionC" });

    var groupedDocuments = Documents.GroupBy(item => new { item.DocumentType, item.Id })
   .ToList();
    DoSomethingB(groupedDocuments) // I want to pass groupedDocuments here
    }
    public void DoSomethingB() // how to define this grouped list here in argument?
    {
      // ...Something
    }
}
```

Comment: @SharathNS - There's nothing in this question that requires any IDE.  The question is valid even if you are using a simple text editor.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass a LINQ result to a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33805790/how-to-pass-a-linq-result-to-a-method)

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint, while an IDE is not required, it helps by revealing the resulting type or even by creating the (empty) method automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using an anonymous type `new { item.DocumentType, item.Id }` as key. This type has no name and cannot be specified in a parameter list. Use a tuple type instead `(item.DocumentType, item.Id)`:

```cs
var groupedDocuments = Documents
    .GroupBy(item => (item.DocumentType, item.Id))
    .ToList();
```

Now, you can declare the method as

```cs
void DoSomethingB(List<IGrouping<(string DocumentType, int Id), Document>> docs)
{
}
```

---

Note that if you delete the `DoSomethingB` method and try to call it with:

```cs
DoSomethingB(groupedDocuments);
```

... the call will show with red squiggly lines, but you can type <kbd>Ctrl-.</kbd> (Control + dot) in Visual Studio to get a list of possible refactorings. You can also hover over the faulty code and a smart tag will appear. Both will offer you the possibility to generate the method automatically, resulting in:

```cs
private static void DoSomethingB(List<IGrouping<(string DocumentType, int Id), Document>> groupedDocuments)
{
    // TODO: Add your implementation
}
```

---

It may not be necessary to call `.ToList()` in the query. If you don't, you get the type `IEnumerable<IGrouping<(string DocumentType, int Id), Document>>` instead. Depending on what `DoSomethingB` does, this will save you an unnecessary allocation of a collection.

See also: [IEnumerable vs List - What to Use? How do they work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3628425/880990)

Comment: I would transform the `IGrouping` to eg. ValueTuple `.Select(x => (x.Key, x.ToList()).ToList();`